# Repurpose Fn+Arrow keys to control brightness on laptops

Tags: 20.04, brightness, shortcut-keys

I have a Lenovo X1 Carbon 7th Gen, where the brightness control keys are on the top row. Being a DELL veteran, I wanted to see if I could use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> to raise and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> to lower brightness.

Using `evtest`, Those combinations show up (understandably) only once as `KEY_WAKEUP` and `KEY_SLEEP` and they seem to be mapped in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev`

```
...
<I150> = 150;   // #define KEY_SLEEP               142
<I151> = 151;   // #define KEY_WAKEUP              143
...
```

I have no need of a sleep or a wakeup key. How could I re-use these keys to `XF86MonBrightnessUp` and `XF86MonBrightnessDown`?